# Apache Rewrite Rule Remove Params with Proxy Reverse

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I am a bit green when it comes to rewrite rules and am looking for help. I have a requirement to do things:

1. Use apache to be a reverse proxy
2. Strip some params from a url in case of parameter hacking.

I have a url, something like:

`http://server.com/search?param1=xxxx&param2=yyyy&param3===zzzz`

or

`http://server.com/search?param2=xxxx&param1=yyyy&param3===zzzz`

You get the idea, the parameters could be in any order.

I want my end point server to only get param2=CONST. So I was stripping the param2 and adding my own.

To complicate things further, this can't be in `.htaccess` but `httpd.conf` (subtle difference in rewrite rules).

Here is what I have currently (not matching correctly).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
ProxyPreserveHost On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+&)?param2=(.*)&(.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/search$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/search?%1%2&%3&param2=XXXXXX [R=301,L]


ProxyPass /search http://localhost:8080/search
ProxyPassReverse /search http://localhost:8080/search
```

---

UPDATE

---

I got it working with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !site=MY_CONST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(^site=[a-zA-Z0-9]+&?|^&site=[a-zA-Z0-9]+&|&site=[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(&?.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/search$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/search?%1%3&site=MY_CONST [L,R=301,NS]
```

The first condition gets you out of the infinite recursion of rewriting a rule to the same resource (so it can be proxied).

Hope it helps.